# Failed: Cannot read property 'isDisplayed' of undefined

Tags: protractor

Can anyone explain me, what am I doing wrong?
definition in `PageObject` (`commonPO`):

```
var mainNavDashboard = element(by.css("mat-toolbar[class=mat-toolbar]")).element(by.css("mat-icon[svgicon=dashboard]"));
```

spec:

```
var common = require('./pages/commonPO');
expect(common.mainNavDashboard.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

Edit:
HTML snippet:

```
<mat-toolbar _ngcontent-c12="" class="mat-toolbar mat-primary mat-toolbar-single-row" color="primary" ng-reflect-color="primary" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;"><div _ngcontent-c12="" class="main-nav" ng-reflect-ng-class="main-nav"><a _ngcontent-c12="" class="nav-button mat-button" mat-button="" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false"><span class="mat-button-wrapper"><div _ngcontent-c12="" class="arrow"></div><mat-icon _ngcontent-c12="" class="mat-icon" role="img" svgicon="dashboard" aria-hidden="true" ng-reflect-svg-icon="dashboard"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fit="" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
    <path d="M3 13h8V3H3v10zm0 8h8v-6H3v6zm10 0h8V11h-8v10zm0-18v6h8V3h-8z"></path>
</svg></mat-icon><span _ngcontent-c12="">Pulpit</span></span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger=""></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></a></mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: pls share the HTML code snippet

Comment: added html snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your given code, the `mainNavDashboard` is not a member/property of the `commonPO`.

You can define `commonPO` as following:

```
var CommonPO = function() {};

CommonPO.prototype.mainNavDashboard = element(by.css("mat-toolbar[class=mat-toolbar]"))
                                     .element(by.css("mat-icon[svgicon=dashboard]"));


module.exports = new CommonPO();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var common = require('./pages/commonPO');

//creating oject for the class
var common1 = new common();

expect(common1.mainNavDashboard.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

Hope it helps you

For more info,Referhttps://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html